# Aligning columns using an awk script file

Tags: csv, awk, formatting

I'm trying to figure out how to write a .awk script that takes a .csv file as input and outputs it without commas and with columns aligned. So far I've tried this :

```
{ printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $2, $3 ,$4 }
```

But this only outputs the data in the first two fields aligned. It does a good job of removing the comma delimiters but there's commas within double quotes in the fourth column that I wonder if will cause an issue. Any guidance is much appreciated I'm very new using awk.

Sample input is like:

```
Name,Last Name,Gender,Pet
Kit,Rattenberie,Male,"Crake, african black"
Cliff,Lakes,Male,"Red phalarope"
Tirrell,Stables,Male,"Rhea, greater"
Cherry,William,Female,"Crow, house"
```

Desired output will be something like:

```
Name    Last Name    Gender   Pet
Kit     Rattenberie  Male    "Crake, african black"
Cliff   Lakes        Male    "Red phalarope"
Tirrell Stables      Male    "Rhea, greater"
Cherry  William      Female  "Crow, house"
```

For a .csv file of 10 rows. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add sample input as well

Comment: sure thing, just added. I'm not sure the max width of each column but it's not more than 25 characters per cell. output delimiter would just be whatever amount of spaces aligns the data

Comment: Yeah I guess my example wasn't ideal. Since the words are varying lengths the amount of spaces would have to vary as well I suppose

Comment: @markp-fuso I edited the examples to be a bit more accurate

Comment: parsing a general purpose CSV with `awk` isn't trivial, even with GNU `awk`. What are the border cases? Are there fields with a newline or a double quote as part of the data? Also. don't you need to double-quote `"Last Name"` in the output?

Answer (score 5):

Using [miller](/questions/tagged/miller) we can transform the input data from CSV to "pretty print" format with a command line option:

```bash
mlr --c2p cat ./input
```

```
Name    Last Name   Gender Pet
Kit     Rattenberie Male   Crake, african black
Cliff   Lakes       Male   Red phalarope
Tirrell Stables     Male   Rhea, greater
Cherry  William     Female Crow, house
```

It drops the quotes though. The `--barred` option is nice too:

```bash
mlr --c2p --barred cat ./input
```

```
+---------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
| Name    | Last Name   | Gender | Pet                  |
+---------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
| Kit     | Rattenberie | Male   | Crake, african black |
| Cliff   | Lakes       | Male   | Red phalarope        |
| Tirrell | Stables     | Male   | Rhea, greater        |
| Cherry  | William     | Female | Crow, house          |
+---------+-------------+--------+----------------------+
```

---

An awk technique that's more programming: keep track of the max width of each column while you're reading the input file, then use that to print the data at the end: this is essentially re-implementing `column -t`

```bash
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            data[NR][i] = $i
            if (length($i) > maxw[i]) maxw[i] = length($i)
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=length(data[i]); j++) {
                printf "%-*s  ", maxw[j], data[i][j]
            }
            printf "\n"
        }
    }
' ./input
```

```
Name     Last Name    Gender  Pet
Kit      Rattenberie  Male    "Crake, african black"
Cliff    Lakes        Male    "Red phalarope"
Tirrell  Stables      Male    "Rhea, greater"
Cherry   William      Female  "Crow, house"
```

Comment: Aah this looks good but I'm supposed to be using a .awk script

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can use this:

```bash
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = sprintf("%-12s", $i)} 1' file

Name     Last Name    Gender  Pet
Kit      Rattenberie  Male    "Crake, african black"
Cliff    Lakes        Male    "Red phalarope"
Tirrell  Stables      Male    "Rhea, greater"
Cherry   William      Female  "Crow, house"
```

Or if width is totally unpredictable then use this `awk + column` solution:

```bash
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1} 1' file |
column -s';' -t

Name     Last Name    Gender  Pet
Kit      Rattenberie  Male    "Crake, african black"
Cliff    Lakes        Male    "Red phalarope"
Tirrell  Stables      Male    "Rhea, greater"
Cherry   William      Female  "Crow, house"
```

If you want to create an awk script then use:

```bash
cat col.awk

BEGIN {
   FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+"
   OFS=";"
}
{$1 = $1}
1
```

Use it as:

```bash
awk -f col.awk file.csv | column -s';' -t
```

Comment: Hmm I'm running this from a .awk file so I'm getting some syntax errors, example run is like awk -F"," -f script.awk file.csv

Comment: What's output of `awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1} 1' file.csv | column -s';' -t` ?

Comment: So I suppose I only put the FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]+' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1} 1' in the BEGIN{} block in my script file and then apply column -t when invoking it? This brings errors though

Comment: check my updated answer to create a `col.awk` script and use it

Comment: If you want to declare FPAT in the BEGIN block, you can't use single quotes and have to escape doubles: `BEGIN {FPAT = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+"}`

Comment: If it worked out, consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea using `*.awk` script (per OP's comment), and having `awk` determine the max width of each column:

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+" }                            # instead of parsing on field delimiter (via FS) ... parse on field format via (FPAT)
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            w[i]= length($i) > w[i] ? length($i) : w[i]      # keep track of max width of each column
        lines[FNR]=$0                                        # save entire line
      }
END   { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) {                               # loop through each saved line
            n=patsplit(lines[i],a)                           # reparse based on FPAT, storing fields in array a[]
            for (j=1;j<n;j++)                                # loop through array entries ...
                printf "%-*s%s", w[j], a[j], OFS             # printing to stdout
            print a[n]                                       # print last field plus "\n"
        }
      }
```

Or using a multi-dimensional array to store the input thus eliminating the 2nd parsing (via `patsplit()`) of the input data:

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+" }
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            w[i]= length($i) > w[i] ? length($i) : w[i]
            fields[FNR][i]=$i
        }
      }
END   { for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++) {
            for (j=1;j<NF;j++)
                printf "%-*s%s", w[j], fields[i][j], OFS
            print fields[i][NF]
        }
      }
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes entire file can fit into memory (via the `awk/lines[]` or `awk/fields[][]` array)
- requires `GNU awk` for `FPAT` and multi-dimensional array support

Both of these generate:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Name    Last Name   Gender Pet
Kit     Rattenberie Male   "Crake, african black"
Cliff   Lakes       Male   "Red phalarope"
Tirrell Stables     Male   "Rhea, greater"
Cherry  William     Female "Crow, house"
```

Comment: Nice and tidy. The final printf _could_ just be `print a[n]` -- we don't really care how long it is